# What is wrong with my dynamic append td in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where each row contains two elements:

```
<table>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td></tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to append a cell with "D" into the last row (the 2nd row that is already there in the current table), but am having difficulty.

I tried to perform:

```
$("table").children().get(1).append("<td>D</td>");
```

and

```
var elem = $("<td/>", {
    text: 'D'
});

$("table").children().get(1).appendChild(elem);
```

and I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
```

Putting tbody in there does not work either:

```
$("table tbody").children().get(1).appendChild(elem);
```

What is to proper way to do this?

I do not want to depend on just the "last td" as assuming I had another element "E", I would want it to automatically add to a third row by itself as opposed to tacking it on as a third column at the end of the 2nd row.

Comment: In all likelihood, the browser is automatically wrapping all the `<tr>`s inside a `<tbody>`, so they aren't direct children of the `<table>` anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can append dynamically by finding next letter from existed letter.May be You need to modify as per your requirement.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table><button type="button" id="addanother" >Add</button>
```

JS :

```
$('#addanother').on('click',function(){
    var length=$('table').find('td:last').parent().children().length;
    var text=$('table').find('td:last').text();
     var nextlet=nextLetter(text);
    if(length == 2){
         $('table').find('tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+nextlet+'</td></tr>');
    }else if(length == 1){
           $('table').find('td:last').after('<td>'+nextlet+'</td>');
    }
  });

// To get alphabets from A-Z from a-z
  function nextLetter(s){
return s.replace(/([a-zA-Z])[^a-zA-Z]*$/, function(a){
    var c= a.charCodeAt(0);
    switch(c){
        case 90: return 'A';
        case 122: return 'a';
        default: return String.fromCharCode(++c);
    }
});
```

}

Fiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/j98H7/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("table td:last").after("<td>D</td>");
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yeEgv/1/)

Results in the structure:

```
<table>
<tbody><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: I want to add "D" to the 2nd row that already exists in the table.

Comment: The answer you provide depends on "td". What if I wanted to add an element "E" into the third row of the table (assuming each row can only contain 2 columns). Is there a better approach than this?

Comment: If you're looking for a generic solution to a variety of possibilities I suggest you update your question to be more specific and provide examples of what you want.

Comment: Just looking for the best solution for the case aforementioned. Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('<td>D</td>').appendTo('table tr:eq(1)');
```